# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que una expresión regular me controle cadenas específicas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validación

Hasta ahora he realizado la siguiente expresión:

```
(^\+{1}5{1}6{1})(2{1,2}|9{1}|[2-3]{2}$)
```

Con el objetivo de cumplir con estas reglas:

1. Si o si debe empezar con '+56'
2. Después debe contener un '2', o un '9', o un '22' o un '23'.
3. El tamaño mínimo permitido es de 4 dígitos en total.
4. El tamaño máximo permitido es de 5 dígitos en total.

La expresión la utilizaré con javascript, si es posible con jQuery mejor. ¿Alguna ayuda, por favor?

**Ejemplos:**

- **Largo 1, 2 o 3**
- +, +5, +56 [Incorrecto, *El largo mínimo debe ser 4, incluyendo el "+"*]
- **Largo 4**
- +569   [Correcto]
- +562   [Correcto]
- +563   [Incorrecto, *Solo un 2 o un 9 pueden ir después del +56*]
- **Largo 5**
- +5622  [Correcto]
- +5623  [Correcto]
- +5677  [Incorrecto, *7 o 77 no es parte de los números permitidos(2,22,23,9)*]

Comment: El número `+5627` sería correcto o incorrecto? (Es decir, después de +562 puede ir cualquier número o solo 2 o 3 para formar un 22 / 23)

Comment: El signo `+` cuenta para el total de la longitud?

Comment: Respuesta 1: +5627 sería incorrecto. Ya que el 7 no sería válido.   Respuesta 2: Efectivamente, el signo + se incluye en el largo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo esta expresión regular que posiblemente cumpla tus requerimientos.

```
var regex = /^\+56(2|9|22|23)$/;
```

La expresión regular de arriba, debería servir para cadenas de caracteres que cumplan con el patrón, como `+569` o `+5623`.

Para verificar el tamaño podrías usar el atributo `length` de la cadena de caracteres que estés evaluando, por ejemplo:

```
if(cadena.length === 4 || cadena.length === 5){
    if(regex.test( cadena )){
        //La cadena de carácteres tiene una longitud de 4 o 5 carácteres
        //y cumple con el patrón
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, solo cadenas de 4 o 5 carácteres cumplirán con el patrón.

Comment: Tu expresión regular está forzando a que la cadena tenga de 3 a 4 dígitos. Si antes por código comrpuebas que tenga 4 o 5 la única opción posible es que la cadena tenga 4 dígitos, pero por los requerimientos de OP también debería permitir 5.

Comment: Así es, mi expresión regular solo valida cadenas de caracteres de 3 o 4 `digitos`, sin embargo, pienso que en la pregunta se está contando al carácter `+` como digito, es decir, se tiene en cuenta como parte del tamaño máximo o mínimo.

Comment: Duda razonable. Preguntemos a OP :)

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con la siguiente expresión regular:

```
^[+]56(?:2[23]?|9\d?)$
```

Tienes una demo [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/sEemIF/2/).

Un ejemplo de validación con javascript podría ser:

```js
var pruebas =
[ '+4091','+5621','+5624','+5625','+56239','+56913','+5620',
  '+562','+5622','+5623','+569','+5622','+5623','+5691','+5692',
  '+5693','+5694','+5695','+5696','+5697','+5698','+5699','+5690' ];

pruebas.forEach(x => {
 console.log(
  'El número: ' + x + ' ' +
  (/^[+]56(?:2[23]?|9\d?)$/m.test(x) ? 'SÍ' : 'NO') +
  ' hace match'
 );
});
```

**La expresión regular explicada:**

```
^              # Inicio de cadena
  [+]          # Caracter '+'. Debe escaparse con \+ o [+]
  56           # 56, literal
  (?:          # Grupo de opciones...
    2[23]?  |  # Opc 1) Un '2' que tiene que ir seguido de un '2' o '3' (opcional)
    9\d?       # Opc 2) Un '9' que puede ir seguido opcionalmente de cualquier otro número
  )            # Fin de grupo de opciones
$              # Final de la cadena.
```

Answer (score 0):

Me habría gustado encontrar en tu pregunta algunos ejemplos.

A lo mejor esto te puede servir:

```
\+56(2|9)[0-9]{1,2}
```

- Empieza con '+56'
- Sigue un 2 o un 9

Si tamaño mínimo permitido es de 4 dígitos después del 2 puede venir cualquier otro dígito incluso un 2 o un 3 conque la segunda regla puede quedarse en  *Después debe contener un '2', o un '9'*

- Ya son tres dígitos: `+562` o `+569`. Lo que quiere decir que necesites uno o dos dígitos más:`[0-9]{1,2}`

https://regex101.com/r/u4AxDf/1

Si esto no contesta tu pregunta ¿puedes por favor añadir unos cuantos ejemplos?

Comment: Si lo he entendido bien después de +562 solo puede venir un 2 o un 3 y con esa expresión regular estarías permitiendo otros casos como `+5628`

Comment: Debe empezar con '+56' Después debe contener un '2', o un '9', o un '22' o un '23'.  Esto quiere decir que después del 2 puede venir un 2 o un 3 o cualquier otro dígito ya que el tamaño mínimo permitido es de 4 dígitos en total.

Comment: Creo que no está redacatado de la mejor manera posible, quizás OP lo pueda explicar. Pero que sentido tendría decir que después del 56 debe venir un 9 o un 22/23? Si después de un 2 pudiese venir cualquier número, no tendría sentido aclarar que puede ser 22 o 23. Pido aclaración a OP en la pregunta original...